# Is it good to create some intermediate table or directly use WITH query. Given that the table is a big table

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, common-table-expression

Is It good to directly move intermediate tables (not-reusable) directly by WITH sub queries.

```
--Create one big intermediate table
CREATE TABLE very_big_table_1 as 
select * from very_big_table_a a, very_big_table_b b where a.key=b.key;

--Create next big intermediate table    
CREATE TABLE very_big_table_2 as 
select * from very_big_table_x x, very_big_table_y y where x.key=y.key;

--Some analytic using intermediate table
Select * from very_big_table_1 a, very_big_table_2 b  where  a.key=b.key;
```

I am in plan to replace it WITH

```
--Using WITH
WITH
very_big_table_1 as (select * from big_table_a a, big_table_b b where a.key=b.key),
very_big_table_2 as (select * from big_table_x x, big_table_y y where x.key=y.key)
Select * from very_big_table_2 a, very_big_table_1 b where  a.key=b.key;
```

yes, Syntactically and Logically this is fine, But I have more than 500 such case in my entire PL/SQL engine which executes in parallel jobs.

***My Question is, will there be any MEMORY or Query Performance issue because of moving very big intermediate tables into WITH sub-queries. One of my objective is to optimize storage.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try it.

Oracle does not (necessarily) materialize CTEs.  That means that the entire query gets optimized, which no unnecessary reads and writes.  In many cases, this results in a more efficient query plan.

However, temporary tables have two or maybe three advantages.  The first is that they have more accurate statistics.  Hence, the optimization engine can do a better job of choosing the best query plan.  Second, you can add indexes on them to further improve performance.

The third advantage is when the same subquery result is used by multiple queries.  Then the contents of the temporary table do not need to be re-run.

So, there isn't a general rule here.  You should try it out query by query.  In general, I prefer to have all the logic in a single query, using CTEs.  For performance reasons, I do sometimes break things out into temporary tables.